# rails 5 undefine template error

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, ajax, ruby-on-rails-5

i am creating rails 5 and adding comment to a show action which is displayed in modal

in my show action for comment i have it like this

```
    @selfie = Selfy.find(params[:id])
    respond_to do |format|
        format.js
    end
```

with this i cant get the show through modal like this

```
<%= link_to fetch_selfy_path(selfie.id), class: "show_lightbox", data: { featherlight: "mylightbox" }, remote: true do %>

      <img class="card-main-image" src="<%= selfie.photo.url if selfie.photo.url  %>" alt="Image Alt text">
    <% end %>
<div class="lightbox" id="lightbox">
    <%=render partial: "selfies/show", locals: { selfie: selfie }  %>
</div>
```

after clicking on the button we show action together with a comment

```
  <% selfie.comments.each do |comment| %>
              <%= render partial: "selfies/comments/comment",  locals: { comment: comment } %>
            <% end %>
```

where the partial looks like

```
  <p> <b><%= comment.user.username %>: </b><%= comment.body %></p>
```

all this works fine until i try to inject the new commect through ajax

```
addCommentToSelfie("<%= j render "selfies/comments/comment", locals: { comment: @comment } %>");
```

this returns and error of

```
ActionView::Template::Error (undefined local variable or method `comment' for #<#<Class:0x007f207400c648>:0x00557937265830>):
    1: 
    2:   <p> <b><%= comment.user.username %>: </b><%= comment.body %></p>

app/views/selfies/comments/_comment.html.erb:2:in `_app_views_selfies_comments__comment_html_erb__4557429192479440105_46989553619000'
```

i tried different methond but still getting same error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're mixing up different syntaxes with some mixing up of quotes too. If you use `locals: ...` you must also use `partial:`, or omit both in this case...

```
addCommentToSelfie("<%= j render 'selfies/comments/comment', comment: @comment %>");
```

Comment: corrected that but still getting same error

`ActionView::Template::Error (undefined local variable or method `comment' for #<#<Class:0x007f207400c648>:0x007f209e0295c0>):
    1: 
    2:   <p> <b><%= comment.user.username %>: </b><%= comment.body %></p>
`

Comment: now am getting `ActionView::Template::Error (undefined method `user' for nil:NilClass):
`

Comment: Well, then your `@comment` is nil, that you're passing into the partial. You'll have to trace that error, probably to the controller action which handles that.

Comment: Good, if you need help with that you can always post a new question here.

Answer (score 0):

based on the answers provide above, i was able to solve my issue

first i clean my creat.js.erb to

```
$("#comments").append("<%= j render partial:  'selfies/comments/comment', locals: { comment: @comment } %>");
```

secondy  was getting error nil class because i wasnt using instant variable in my comments controller

from:

```
def create
  comment =  @selfie.comments.new(comment_params)
  comment.user = current_user
  comment.save

  end
```

TO:

```
def create
  @comment =  @selfie.comments.new(comment_params)
  @comment.user = current_user
  @comment.save
  respond_to do |format|
      format.js
  end
```

from there everything works smoothly

Answer (score -1):

Could you show us the action create in the comment controller ? Usually, I do something like that.

```
  def create
    @comment = @selfie.comments.new(comment_params)
    @comment.user = current_user
    respond_to do |format|
      if @comment.save
        format.html { redirect_to @comment }
        format.js
      else
        render :new
      end
    end
  end
```

Then in your view, you should have the file comments/create.js.erb that contains your js :

```
addCommentToSelfie("<%= j render 'selfies/comments/comment', comment: @comment %>");
```

And now @comment should exist.

Comment: this is my comment controller
```ruby
def create
  @comment =  @selfie.comments.new(comment_params)
  @comment.user = current_user
  @comment.save
```
  end

Comment: I edited my answer (I also made a mistake between format.json and format.js). First, you should post a comment without ajax. To be sure everything works. Then you should add the respond_to ... format.js inside the create action and not in the show action as I supposed you did. It would really help if you show us the comment controller in entire.

Comment: this my whole comment controller

```

class Selfies::CommentsController < ApplicationController
  before_action :authenticate_user!
  before_action :set_selfie
  def create
  @comment =  @selfie.comments.new(comment_params)
  @comment.user = current_user
  @comment.save

  end
private

  def comment_params
    params.require(:comment).permit(:body)
  end

    private

    def set_selfie
        @selfie = Selfy.find(params[:selfy_id])
    end
end
```
anyway right now everything is working except appending data to the modal

Comment: Could you edit your post with it. It will be useful to anybody who want to help you and it will be easier to read.